# Compound Conditional in Lisp

Tags: lisp, conditional-statements

I'm new to lisp and I am simply trying to have two functions called at once if a conditional returns true.

```
(cond 
  ((equals (first expression) "+")
   (function1 parameter)
   (function2 parameter)))
```

In the above code, I just want function1 and function2 to be called. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Common Lisp

- EQUALS does not exist, EQUAL does
- COND already does what you want

COND allows several calls after the test:

```
(cond ((equal (first expression) "+")
       (do-something ...)
       (do-something-more ...)))
```

- It is called Lisp, not LISP
- read a [Beginner Introduction](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/)
- use a [Reference](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm#cond)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, progn like this:

```
(cond 
  ((equals (first expression) "+")
   (progn
     (function1 paramter)
     (function2 parameter))))
```

`cond` takes one expression to evaluate if true. In this use `progn` (with its arguments) is that one expression. `progn`, subsequently take n expressions and evaluates them.

Comment: But but but...`cond` provides an implicit `progn` in every branch, so the use of `progn` here is superfluous. Well, I'm talking about Common Lisp, anyway. Who knows about other dialects of Lisp. :-P

Comment: The body of a COND expression is wrapped in an implicit PROGN, so there is no need to explicitly provide one.